# Show selected ionic list view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created this  ([demo](http://codepen.io/Hin/pen/VLVLrJ)) to demonstrate my problem. In this demo, I have a list page, a button at the header when the checkbox `<ion-checkbox>` attribute is checked, a list view and also a checkbox next to my list view. I want to be able to show the selected list  on my home.html when the submit button is click. I am not sure how to do that. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of what you want to achieve exactly but you could just use `<ion-checkbox>` again with `ng-if="data.checked"`.

`<ion-list>
     <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="data in tempData" ng-if="data.checked" ng-checked="data.checked"> Item {{data.id}} </ion-checkbox>
</ion-list>`

Here an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGQZGR)

Or you could use `<ion-item>` with `ng-if="data.checked"`,

`<ion-item ng-repeat="data in tempData" ng-if="data.checked">
             Item {{data.id}}
          </ion-item>`

Here an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGQZGR)